# SQL - joining two queries against same table for grid output

Tags: sql, self-join

I should probably be able to figure this out from other questions/answers I've read here, but I just can't get anything to work today.  Any help is really appreciated.

I have two queries, counting the instances of "GOOD" feedback, and "BAD" feedback from a single table.  I just want to join them so that I can see something like below

```
ID   |  GOOD |  BAD
121  |   0   |  7
123  |   5   |  0
287  |  32   |  8
```

I'm running numerous queries from VBA, if that matters, and the 0's can just be null. I can clean that stuff up in VBA.

Query 1:

```
select ID, count(*) 
from HLFULL 
where DEPT= 'HLAK' 
  and feedback = 'GOOD' 
group by ID
```

Query 2:

```
select ID, count(*) 
from HLFULL 
where DEPT= 'HLAK' 
  and feedback = 'BAD' 
group by ID
```

I've tried UNION, UNION ALL, JOIN, INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, aggregations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation like this:

```
select ID,
    count(case when feedback = 'GOOD' then 1 end) as Good,
    count(case when feedback = 'BAD' then 1 end) as Bad
from HLFULL
where DEPT = 'HLAK'
    and feedback in ('GOOD', 'BAD')
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the result using conditional aggregation. This type of query uses a `CASE` expression along with your aggregate function to get multiple columns:

```
select ID, 
  count(case when feedback = 'GOOD' then Id end) as Good,
  count(case when feedback = 'BAD' then Id end) as Bad
from HLFULL 
where DEPT= 'HLAK' 
group by ID
```

Comment: This is great too - really appreciate it!